# load multiple files using a for loop and store data in list of lists

Tags: r, list, loops, file-upload

I have a folder in my computer which has multiple folders inside and I would like to load some folders of interest.

For example Folder A has Folder1, Folder2 and Folder3 inside.

Folder 1 has 3 files
Folder 2 has 5 files
Folder 3 has 6 files

I would like to create a for loop that loads Everything inside Folder 1 and Folder 3. The files from each folder I would like to be stored inside a list with the following structure:

```
$Folder 1
$Folder 1[[1]]
    [,1]    [,2]    [,3]
[1,] "chr1" 120532 125086
[2,] "chr2"  13025  13055

$Folder 1[[2]]
    [,1]    [,2]    [,3]
[1,] "chr10" 102532 125086
[2,] "chr12"  10325  10355

$Folder 1[[3]]
    [,1]    [,2]    [,3]
[1,] "chr11" 125032 125086
[2,] "chr12"  10325  10355

$Folder 3
$Folder 3[[1]]
    [,1]    [,2]    [,3]
[1,] "chr6" 102532 120586
[2,] "chr7"  10325  10355
```

and so on.....

So far my code is like this:

```
TFs=unique(TF_hyper_baseline$collection)
data_sets=list()
trans_factor=levels(as.factor(TFs))

for (t in 1:length(trans_factor))
{
  setwd(file.path("D:/Papers to work on/Methylation Meta-Analyses/New analyses - VO2max and aerobic only/UniBind_baseline_hyper/damo_hg38_TFBS_per_TF", trans_factor[[t]]))
  files <- list.files()[grep(".bed",list.files())]
    for (f in files){
    dat<- read_delim(f, col_names = FALSE) 
    data_sets=append(list(data_sets), dat)
  }
  }
```

Everything goes well until the part where the list is being saved (see image), as it starts repeating itself and the names are not saved properly so I don't know which folder the tables are from.

Can anyone help me finding out a solution for this please?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You must not cast your `data_sets` as a `list`:

```
data_sets=append(list(data_sets), dat)
```

It has to be

```
data_sets=append(data_sets, dat)
```

Answer (score 0):

My example structure is like this:

```
~/test/folder_1/test9.csv
~/test/folder_1/test10.csv
~/test/folder_2/test91.csv
~/test/folder_2/test92.csv
```

Now we iterate over this folders and extract `.csv`-files only:

```r
setwd("~/test/")

folders <- list.dirs(full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE)

my_list <- list()

for (fold in folders) {
  files <- list.files(path = file.path(getwd(), fold), pattern = "\\.csv")
  for (file in files) {
    my_list[[fold]][[file]] <- read.csv2(file.path(getwd(), fold, file))
  }
}
```

This returns (yes, the testdata is all the same):

```r
$folder_1
$folder_1$test10.csv
                     x                      y         cdf    abscorr
1   CASE TEST 10 Inlet    CASE TEST 10 Outlet  0.94460489 0.94460489
2   CASE TEST 10 Inlet     CASE TEST 10 Total  0.87480985 0.87480985
3  CASE TEST 10 Outlet     CASE TEST 10 Total  0.69187830 0.69187830
4  CASE TEST 10 Outlet       CASE TEST 10 BOX  0.52404316 0.52404316
5   CASE TEST 10 Total       CASE TEST 10 BOX  0.94397362 0.94397362
6   CASE TEST 10 Total CASE TEST 10 BOX Total  0.68779904 0.68779904
7     CASE TEST 10 BOX  CASE TEST 10 BOX Flow  0.51054070 0.51054070
8     CASE TEST 10 BOX        CASE TEST 10 1A  0.98907793 0.98907793
9      CASE TEST 10 1A      CASE TEST 10 Gett -0.58787388 0.58787388
10     CASE TEST 10 2A    CASE TEST 10 Outlet  0.03679823 0.03679823
11     CASE TEST 10 3A        CASE TEST 10 4A  0.78073388 0.78073388
12     CASE TEST 10 4A    CASE TEST 10 Outlet  0.11699066 0.11699066
13  CASE TEST 10 Delta     CASE TEST 10 Inlet  0.77080311 0.77080311

$folder_1$test9.csv
                    x                     y         cdf    abscorr
1   CASE TEST 9 Inlet    CASE TEST 9 Outlet  0.94460489 0.94460489
2   CASE TEST 9 Inlet     CASE TEST 9 Total  0.87480985 0.87480985
3  CASE TEST 9 Outlet     CASE TEST 9 Total  0.69187830 0.69187830
4  CASE TEST 9 Outlet       CASE TEST 9 BOX  0.52404316 0.52404316
5   CASE TEST 9 Total       CASE TEST 9 BOX  0.94397362 0.94397362
6   CASE TEST 9 Total CASE TEST 9 BOX Total  0.68779904 0.68779904
7     CASE TEST 9 BOX  CASE TEST 9 BOX Flow  0.51054070 0.51054070
8     CASE TEST 9 BOX        CASE TEST 9 1A  0.98907793 0.98907793
9      CASE TEST 9 1A      CASE TEST 9 Gett -0.58787388 0.58787388
10     CASE TEST 9 2A    CASE TEST 9 Outlet  0.03679823 0.03679823
11     CASE TEST 9 3A        CASE TEST 9 4A  0.78073388 0.78073388
12     CASE TEST 9 4A    CASE TEST 9 Outlet  0.11699066 0.11699066
13  CASE TEST 9 Delta     CASE TEST 9 Inlet  0.77080311 0.77080311


$folder_2
$folder_2$test91.csv
                    x                     y         cdf    abscorr
1   CASE TEST 9 Inlet    CASE TEST 9 Outlet  0.94460489 0.94460489
2   CASE TEST 9 Inlet     CASE TEST 9 Total  0.87480985 0.87480985
3  CASE TEST 9 Outlet     CASE TEST 9 Total  0.69187830 0.69187830
4  CASE TEST 9 Outlet       CASE TEST 9 BOX  0.52404316 0.52404316
5   CASE TEST 9 Total       CASE TEST 9 BOX  0.94397362 0.94397362
6   CASE TEST 9 Total CASE TEST 9 BOX Total  0.68779904 0.68779904
7     CASE TEST 9 BOX  CASE TEST 9 BOX Flow  0.51054070 0.51054070
8     CASE TEST 9 BOX        CASE TEST 9 1A  0.98907793 0.98907793
9      CASE TEST 9 1A      CASE TEST 9 Gett -0.58787388 0.58787388
10     CASE TEST 9 2A    CASE TEST 9 Outlet  0.03679823 0.03679823
11     CASE TEST 9 3A        CASE TEST 9 4A  0.78073388 0.78073388
12     CASE TEST 9 4A    CASE TEST 9 Outlet  0.11699066 0.11699066
13  CASE TEST 9 Delta     CASE TEST 9 Inlet  0.77080311 0.77080311

$folder_2$test92.csv
                     x                      y         cdf    abscorr
1   CASE TEST 10 Inlet    CASE TEST 10 Outlet  0.94460489 0.94460489
2   CASE TEST 10 Inlet     CASE TEST 10 Total  0.87480985 0.87480985
3  CASE TEST 10 Outlet     CASE TEST 10 Total  0.69187830 0.69187830
4  CASE TEST 10 Outlet       CASE TEST 10 BOX  0.52404316 0.52404316
5   CASE TEST 10 Total       CASE TEST 10 BOX  0.94397362 0.94397362
6   CASE TEST 10 Total CASE TEST 10 BOX Total  0.68779904 0.68779904
7     CASE TEST 10 BOX  CASE TEST 10 BOX Flow  0.51054070 0.51054070
8     CASE TEST 10 BOX        CASE TEST 10 1A  0.98907793 0.98907793
9      CASE TEST 10 1A      CASE TEST 10 Gett -0.58787388 0.58787388
10     CASE TEST 10 2A    CASE TEST 10 Outlet  0.03679823 0.03679823
11     CASE TEST 10 3A        CASE TEST 10 4A  0.78073388 0.78073388
12     CASE TEST 10 4A    CASE TEST 10 Outlet  0.11699066 0.11699066
13  CASE TEST 10 Delta     CASE TEST 10 Inlet  0.77080311 0.77080311
```

This could be done using `apply`-functions, but I choose to use a `for`-loop for better readability and I think it's easier to understand.